# How to solve for Lipschitz constant?

Tags: real-analysis, lipschitz-functions

Please, how do I show that the Lipschitz constant is 8 Given the function $f(x) =x^2$ on $[-1, 4]$. It was a given assignment which I have been trying to solve.  I just need a hint on how to solve it

Comment: What is the largest value the derivative can take on that interval?

Comment: I think it is 4

Comment: Can you write down the derivative and can you decide whether it is increasing or decreasing and what can you say about the largest value an increasing function can take on a closed interval.

Comment: F'(X) =2x and f"(X) =2

Answer (score 2):

For $x,y\in [-1,4]$ we have $|x^2-y^2|= |x-y|\cdot |x+y|\leq |x-y|(|x|+|y|)\leq |x-y|(4+4)=8|x-y|$. This is the sharpest possible, because if $x=4$ and $y=4(1-2^{-n})$ then $|x^2-y^2|/|x-y|=8-4^{-n}.$ Another way to do this is to observe that $d(x^2)/dx=2x.$ So for $-1\leq x< y\leq 4$ we have $|x^2-y^2|\leq |x-y|\cdot \max \{|2z| :z\in [x,y]\}\leq 8|x-y|.$